# Avoiding SonarQube duplication for DTO and Model private variables and getter setters JAVA

Tags: java, getter-setter, code-duplication

I have a Model class in MODEL package and its corresponding DTO class in DTO package. Model class is used to accept request parameters and send response. DTO class is used to map with database through Hibernate ORM. (i.e,

- I accept userModel, then I convert it into userDTO using dozermapper
- Then I save(userDTO)
- Then I map userDTO back to model using and return userModel in response

  ```
  public class UserModel {
      private int userId;
      private String email;
      /*private getter and setters of all members*/
  }

  public class UserDTO {        
      private int userId;
      private String email;
      /*private getter and setters of all members*/
  }
  ```

I have just started using SonarQube which shows duplicacy for the variables and its getters and setters.

How can we use the variables from DTO in Model or from Model in DTO without having any main method?

Comment: Why use 2 classes instead of 1?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Its not that DTOs and Models will always have same and equal fields. Models can have extra fields too which will not be corresponding to database columns. Only  DTO's fields are corresponding to database columns

Comment: What do you mean by "How can we use...without having any main method"? The design of having two separate classes for this seems reasonable to me anyways, even if it happens to have same fields (for now).

Comment: Same issue here, I rather separate my model and my api bean, but sonar report duplication, any way to avoid that ?